# Will about 10 loose hairs in a violin bow make any difference when I use it?

Tags: strings, violin, maintenance, bow

[image: close-up of hairs strings]

It's something like the image above, just less loose hairss. While I was looking at it, I tried playing the violin, and some hairs got loose.

Do I just cut them off or yank them off? This little book that came with it said, "Do not attempt your own repairs. Only an expert musical instrument repairman has the skill and experience to repair the instrument."

Comment: What happens if you tighten the bow a little?

Comment: When was your bow last rehaired?  Do you make sure to completely detension your bow when done playing (every time)?

Comment: Could you post a picture of your bow?

Answer (score 2):

All the hairs should tighten at about the same rate. That bow looks very slack. If individual hairs break, they can be pulled out or cut off - I've seen concert violinists do this mid concert - usually snatched off.

If all the hairs don't tighten together, it's a job for a techie.

Answer (score 1):

I would carefully cut them off rather than yank them out.  The latter might loosen still more.  If it keeps happening, you should take it to a reputable repairer and find out what the problem is.